# Tab to move vertical instead of horizontal in ASP.net Form

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, user-interface

We have around 100 dropdowns in one ASP.net form. When we hit tab it takes to the next dropdown to the right. Instead I want it to the dropdown below.

How can I do this?

Comment: I hope I never have to fill out your form :)

Comment: Good point @Marcie... I hope this flow is actually intuitive when it's on the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1:

***Cumbersome:*** you can set the `tabIndex` on your controls.

### Option 2:

***Extensible:*** you can wire a JavaScript function to the `onblur` event of the control and calculate the `ID` of the next control based on the `sender` of the `onblur` event and set the focus to it.

Comment: hehehe i liked the Cumbersome option